# WinForm - Incorrect syntax in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I have now erased my code to replace it with this. But now the rest of the code wont work, can someone help?
I'm trying to create a login system using a ComboBox for the usernames, but since I changed it I just get errors thrown back. The latest error is: *Invalid Syntax where "'"

Full Error Message: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - {"Incorrect syntax near '.'."}`

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using BarcodeForm.Properties;



private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    const string Connectionstring = "Data Source=GARETH-PC1;Initial Catalog=Genres;Integrated Security=True";
    var query = "Select Username From Login Where Username =@uname AND Password=@pwd";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", ComboBox1.SelectedText);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", textBox2.Text);
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Hide();

        var ss = new Main();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
    }

    private void Form1Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginTableAdapter.Fill(genresDataSet2.Login);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the content of ComboBox1.SelectedText and textBox2.Text?

Comment: Or just something alike, especially if it contains special chars like (', ", /...) and so on...

Are you sure the parameters are of correct type. Your code looks to be correct...

Comment: Your three questions seem to be all the same issue.  Please try to resolve one question before asking the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether this is the issue but could it be the spacing?

Username =@uname AND Password=@pwd

goes to

Username = @uname AND Password = @pwd

SQL server doesnt allow no spaces so could be your issue